# How can I virtualize Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, osx-lion

My friend bought Mac OS X Lion for me, but I don't have a Mac as I'm using Windows 7.

Since I have the DVD, which virtual application do I have to use? Which application is allowed by Apple?

Comment: There's a DVD version of Lion?

Comment: As @billc said, you should, uhm, *probably* check if that DVD is genuine :)

Comment: Maybe the friend brought Lion in the Mac appstore and burned it on a DVD..

Comment: @slhck I'm not sure that is genuine or not but i received on a DVD

Answer (score 4):

According to the [OS X EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx107.pdf) you may not install OS X on any hardware that is not apple branded.

> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software.

You do have license to install it as a virtual operating system, but only if it is run on Apple hardware.

Comment: @slhck thanks for editing that in instead of making it your own answer. I really appreciate that.

Comment: It sucks. Even driver developers must buy apple branded equipment to write drivers for OSX. I usually check the classified mid or end of the semester.  Students are usually strapped for cash and 6 month old Macs are going for dirt cheap.