# Run OSX virtually in Windows

Tags: windows, macos

I want to develop for iOS but I have a windows 7 laptop.
I saw a screenshot of OSX run virtually but couldn't see in what application.

Is it possible to run Mac virtually in Windows or not? Anyone tips?

Comment: It should be noted, as I stated in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/324046/49528) that this is not legal, according to the OS X EULA. Also, this question may be a duplicate of my the one in my link.

Comment: Unless you have an Apple computer what you want to do violates the Terms of Use for OS X.  OSX has protections because of TPM security.

Comment: @roviuser: Fortunately for most of us, Apple does not write the laws in the countries we reside in. The enforceability/legality of EULAs is still in dispute. In the U.S., there's no consensus in the court system to the legitimacy of the "sale of a license to use, not sale of a product" perspective, which undermines the consumer right of first sale. Only in the states where [UCITA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Computer_Information_Transactions_Act) has been passed is your statement an actual matter of law. And only 2 states have passed it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download pre-made modified version of snow leopard for vmware 8, you can get more information from [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-install-os-x-snow-leopard-in-vmware-windows-7-9140301/)

Comment: Shortened links are a) unnecessary and b) smell of spam. Please use the full link.

Comment: I just use a plug-in in VIMperator which automatically make shortened links every time I try to copy the url. I think I should be careful using that plugin for this forum :)

Answer (score 2):

Virtualizing OSX on Windows should be possible with VMware and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). The latter is even available for free and a fitting tutorial can be found [here](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows).

Comment: You can only virtualize OSX on an Apple computer using VMWare on VirtualBox respectfully.  At least thats how it suppose to be.